# to get max value in a row from pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

to get max value from pig:

student(rollno,marks)

```
rollno. marks

1   24

2   26

3   50

4   30

5   35
```

output req: max marks roll no.

output:
3 50

suppose A contains the values of student table

how to get rollno. scored max marks

I tried this:

```
B = GROUP A BY rollno

C = foreach B generate group , max( A.marks);
```

but it is resulting all records can any one help me this in pig

Answer (score 9):

The most readable way would be to `ORDER` your data and then choose the top record with `LIMIT 1`:

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (rollno, marks);
B = ORDER A BY marks DESC;
C = LIMIT B 1;
DUMP C;

(3,50)
```

But this is not very efficient in terms of the number of MapReduce jobs that Pig will generate to accomplish it.  You have one map-only job to load the data, another to sample it (required by `ORDER BY`), another to actually do the sorting, and a final one to perform the `LIMIT` and output.  4 jobs for that simple task.  It took me 1:54 to run this, and virtually all of that time was in MapReduce overhead.

But if your input is not too huge, you could just use a nested foreach, and then all that work will take place in a single reducer, which while not as scalable, will be much faster than using MapReduce for every step.  Group everything into one record first, and then use the nested foreach:

```
A = LOAD 'tmp/data.txt' AS (rollno, marks);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B {
        ord = ORDER A BY marks DESC;
        top = LIMIT ord 1;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(top);  
};
DUMP C;

(3, 50)
```

This only used one MapReduce job, and took 0:35.

Of course, if your data is small enough that MapReduce overhead matters, Pig may not be the right tool for what you're doing.  But if you're generating a lot of jobs for a small amount of data, and you do need to use Pig, it's worth trying to use the nested foreach.

Answer (score 3):

as per my understanding, you require single row with max marks and roll no.

Then you have to sort rollno by descending order and take top row with limit key word like below

```
c=order b by marks desc;

d=limit c 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  a = Load 'data.txt' using PigStorage (',');
  b = group a all;
  c = foreach b GENERATE  MAX(a.$1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is working for me -**

```
userRollNoWithMarks = Load 'data.txt' using PigStorage (',');
maxNo = FOREACH(GROUP userRollNoWithMarks ALL) GENERATE  MAX(userRollNoWithMarks .$1);
DUMP maxNo ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
B = GROUP A BY rollno;
C = foreach B generate group , MAX($1.$2);
```

Comment: why do we need to group when we want to get max for all roll no ? the question is to get max across all roll no  ,not for each roll no ..